# Comparing an input to the values of an array only works with a single value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have some fruits names stored in an array. If the user enters a food name which is already stored in the array then `true` should be returned, otherwise `false`.

But it only returns `true` when I input the value `Mango`, otherwise always returning `false`, why?

Here's my code:

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4dfhawg9/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="value" />
<button onclick="check()">test</button>
<p id="pValue">
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myVar;

check = function() {
    myVar = document.getElementById("value").value;

    var fruits = ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango'];

    for(i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if(myVar == fruits[i]) {
            document.getElementById("pValue").innerHTML = "true";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pValue").innerHTML = "false";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using a for increment loop so only the last value will  return true. You can add a `break;` to the loop if you choose to keep this as the method. See updated fiddle below ::

```js
var myVar;


check = function() {
    myVar = document.getElementById("value").value;
    var fruits = ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango'];

    for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if (myVar == fruits[i]) {
            document.getElementById("pValue").innerHTML = "true";
            break;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("pValue").innerHTML = "false";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="value" />
<button onclick="check()">test</button>
<p id="pValue">
</p>
```